# Notepad++ Regex inverse match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm new to Regex and trying to figure out how to remove all text from file open in Notepad++ that does not match `#LCxxxx` or `#LAxxxx`.  Example below (text wanting to keep in bold):

> 1.In rare cases, reinstalling this MSP file can cause the Citrix Display Driver.....
>
> [From ICAWS760WX86][#0528688]
>
> 30.This release includes an enhancement...
>
> [From ICAWS760WX86022][**#LA3014**]
>
> New Fixes in This Release
>
> 1.Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012 R2,...
>
> [From ICAWS760WX86026][**#LC2179**]
>
> Fixes from Replaced Hotfixes
>
> 1.If the Windows Remote Desktop Session Host....
>
> [From ICAWS760WX86004][**#LC1180**]

Comment: Does it have to be a solution with Notepad++? Seems easy enough to run the file through a python script or similar to copy everything that matches to another file.

Comment: You can just do this with `grep`: `grep "#L[AC]...." -o test.txt > output.txt` (On second thought, since Notepad++ is a Windows program, you might not have `grep`...)

Comment: Don't do a search and replace.  Instead do a Find in Files.  That will put all the matches into a window and you can just copy and paste them to a file.

Comment: I found a windows copy of grep -- trying it out.  I'll also try the Search and Replace option. Thanks!

Comment: So I'm using this regular expression for the LC piece but I'm getting the entire line. I want just the #LCxxxx portion. What am i missing? (#)(\w+)

Comment: Not sure whether this also works for your Windows grep clone, but I used the parameter `-o`, or `--only-matching`. BTW, wouldn't your regex also match `#0528688`?

Comment: Yeah you're right, it does

Answer (score 3):

I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/qB4pZ3/2) is what you're looking for:

`(?:[\S\s]*?)(\#L[AC]\d{4})(?:.*)`

Replace with:

`$1\n`

Answer (score 2):

You could do a regular expression search and replace, searching for

```
(#L[AC]....)
```

where "dot matches newline" is NOT selected. Replace with

```
\r\n\1\r\n
```

That will put all the wanted pieces of text on a line on their own.

Next use the "Mark" tab in the find window. Select "Bookmark line", use the same search string as above (the capture brackets are not needed this time, but they are harmless and so can be left), and them click "Mark all". Now all the wanted lines are bookmarked. Use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove unmarked lines**.

There may be a way of doing it all in one go, but that would be a complex regular expression. The method above uses two simple steps.

Answer (score 1):

> remove all text from file open in Notepad++ that does not match #LCxxxx or #LAxxxx

```
^.*(\[#L[CA]\d+\])$|^.*$
```

---

#### DESCRIPTION

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### DEMO

https://regex101.com/r/hO1aL8/2

#### Notepad++

Do a search and replace like describe in the screenshot below:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to get rid off the empty lines during the replace operation, use the regular expression below:

```
^[\S\s]+?(\[#L[CA]\d+\])$
```

- `\s` : Whitespaces (\t,\r,\n ...)
- `\S` : Any character except whitespaces.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Tested on Notepad 6.6.9**

Comment: Thanks this is awesome -- helps to understand how it works as well.  I'd upvote twice if I could

Comment: @bcahill I didn't know if empty lines after replacement are a concern. See my update in my post with the second regex  that remove those empty  lines.

Comment: How do you generate these graphs?

Comment: @FranciscoInacio I used debuggex.com

Comment: @FranciscoInácio I used debuggex.com